# With Nginx / Node.js reverse proxy how does Nginx serve robots.txt despite txt files not being referenced in Nginx config's location blocks?

Tags: nginx, robots.txt

In Chrome when I enter https://www.example.com/robots.txt my `robots.txt` file is served and works fine.  I'm happy that it works but I'm not sure why it does.

In the config below I thought that my last `location` block, `location /` was a catch-all that would attempt to serve every file request that didn't match the regex in one of the `location` blocks above it. In practice I use this block to serve files through my node.js / Express server.

I didn't include a `location ~* \.(txt)$` block therefor I thought `location /` would automatically send requests for `robots.txt` to node.js which would throw an error or otherwise fail to deliver the file.  To my surprise this setup worked fine.  Why is that?

```
server {

    include conf.d/listen-443;

    server_name www.example.com;

    root /srv/example/views/public;

    location ~* \.(jpg|png|svg|webp|ico)$ {
    }

    location ~* \.(css)$ {
    }

    location ~* \.(html)$ {
    }

    location ~* \.(js)$ {
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

}
```

Comment: Stop your Node app and try to reload the file again. What happens?

Comment: Holy smokes good call.  When I turned off node.js the file wasn't sent.  So `location /` was a catch-all but node.js picked up the slack and sent it.